# Chrome gradient in symbol from external svg not rendered

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have a svg file which defines a symbol like that:

test.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1024px" height="1024px" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="id0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#E6E6E6"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="gray"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="fid_group" class="logo">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="url(#id0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I try to use it the following way:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1024px" height="1024px" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="test.svg#fid_group"></use>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox I get the square with the gradient inside, in Chrome I get only the black stroke. Is there something wrong with how I use the gradient or the symbol?

Comment: No, it's just a Chrome bug.

Comment: Is this already reported somewhere? I searched around for a bit but didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know. You could always try reporting it anyway..